# How to overcome combo box ListIndex Overflow error in vba

Tags: combobox, vba6

I'm using combox for listing items which will have more than 60K items. The task I'm doing is in the item list if I select any item the index of the item should be return and assigned to ListIndex property then I will use the ListIndex for other purpose. The problem is since ListIndex max value is 32767 when you have more than this max value it is showing overflow error.

Is there any way to get index values more than 32767 (Other than ListIndex property also fine).

Comment: You don't specify which Office product you are using but what version you're using may make a difference. If you are running a 32 bit version of Office then that is the max value for an integer. If you switch to the 64 bit version I would expect it would use the larger 64bit integer.